# jsf 2.0 single web-application with multiple domains

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have jsf 2.0 web application (with ejb) that will serve multiple domains. I need to load data according to domain name that user came from. So I have to get domain, invoke ejb service and save data in user session. Also, when user go to domainA.com and then change to domainB.com I should create new session.

How this could be done? Servlet, filter, phase listener, post construct in managed bean?
Or maybe create multiple web-apps, one for each domain?

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to use fully qualified domains and not subdomains I would recommend going with the separate deployments for each domain, this solves your issue with the session creation and shouldn't be difficult. You can get the domain name inside you servlets or other components having access to the Request object,  from info associated with the request itself:

```
        // Get client's hostname
        String hostname = req.getRemoteHost(); // hostname
```

This method

> returns the host name of the client sending the request. If the name
>   is unknown, returns an empty string. The fully qualified domain name
>   (e.g. "xyzws.com") of the client that made the request. The IP address
>   is returned if this cannot be determined.

Comment: `HttpServletRequest.getServerName()` is what OP needs - the _receiving_ domain. `getRemoteHost()` is almost useless in a public internet environment.

Comment: Using one deployment would be more flexible and easier to maintain. I think about servlet (for every url /*) and check if remote host==host in user session (if session exist) and if not I would kill old session and start new one. Is it good idea?