# Java multiple domains on a single app

Tags: java, jsf

I am using Java EE / JSF for web app I am developing. The situation is I have X number of clients with separate domain names (123.com, 124.com, etc.). I would like them to all point to the main application deployed with there separate domain names (they all can use a shared ip). However, the site uses managedbeans (login, cart) to have functionality. How would I go about making these managedbeans associated only with 123.com instead of 124.com so that they could not go to the other persons site and hijack the session. Does java have a way to restrict this or give custom scoped session names depending on a specific value set (in this case the domain name)?

The only other question I found on this topic is: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414964/jsf-2-0-single-web-application-with-multiple-domains)

I am new to the java development but have solved this problem on my php applications. Thought it would be beneficial to hear what experienced java developers had to say about this problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Bean scope wont be related to all domains except for the `ApplicationScope` (that will be shared). All others will be created when needed. If you need to handle different tasks conditionnally of the domain, you will have to do it in all beans (or business logic).

Comment: so best method would be to have a check to see if my session in the bean is for (mydomainname + sessionName).